# Performance of an angular 2 application with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

I have been creating a web application using angular2 with firebase (angularfire2),
I want to know if my development method is optimized or not.

When user select a group, I check if he is already member of the group.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if(auth) {
        this.userConnected = auth;
      }
    });

    this.router.params.subscribe(params=>{
      this.idgroup=params['idgroup'];
    });
    this._groupService.getGroupById(this.idgroup).subscribe(
      (group)=>{
        this.group=group;
          this.AlreadyPaticipe(this.group.id,this.userConnected.uid),
      }
    );
}
```

this method is work, but when I place the function `AlreadyPaticipe(this.group.id,this.userConnected.uid)` outside `getGroupById(this.idgroup).subscribe()` ,I get an error group is undefinded ,I now because angular is asynchrone. I don't khow how I can do it?. How I can optimize my code ?,How I can place the function `AlreadyPaticipe(this.group.id,this.userConnected.uid)` outside `getGroupById(this.idgroup).subscribe()`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, what is the purpose of `AlreadyPaticipe` ?

Comment: or you can use a resolve

Comment: AlreadyPaticipe it is a function to check if user is memeber of a group or not .

Answer (score 0):

### Everything as stream :

Well first, you shouldn't subscribe that much, the best practice is to combine your observables into one and subscribe to it just once, because everytime you subscribe, you need to cleanup when your component is destroyed (not for http, neither ActivatedRoute though) and you end up managing your subscription imperatively (which is not the aim of RXjs). You can find [a good article on this topic here](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87#.sftl2sxgd).

You must think everything as a stream, all your properties are observables :

```
this.user$ = this.af.auth.share(); //not sure of the share, I don't know firebase, don't know what it implies...
this.group$ = this.router.params.map(params => params["idgroup"])
    .switchMap(groupID => this.groupService.getGroupById(groupID)).share();
// I imagine that AlreadyPaticipe return true or false, but maybe i'm wrong
this.isMemberOfGroup$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.group$,
    this.user$.filter(user => user !== null)
).flatMap(([group, user]) => this.AlreadyPaticipe(groupID, user.uid));
```

You don't even have to subscribe ! in your template you just need to use the `async` pipe. for example:

```
<span>user: {{user$|async}}</span>
<span>group : {{group$|async}}</span>
<span>member of group : {{isMemberOfGroup$|async}}</span>
```

Or if you don't want to use the pipe, you can combine all those observable and subscribe only once :

```
this.subscription = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.group$,
    this.user$,
    this.isMemberOfGroup$
).do(([group, user, memberofGroup]) => {
    this.group = group;
    this.user = user;
    this.isMemberofGroup = memberofGroup;
}).subscribe()
```

in this case, don't forget to `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` in `ngOnDestroy()`

there is a very handy tool on [rxJS docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) (at the bottom of the page) that helps you to choose the right operator for the right behavior.

### I don't care about streams, I want it to work, quick n' dirty :

If You don't want to change your code too much, you could use a Resolve guard that will fetch the data before your component is loaded. [Take a look at the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard):

> In summary, you want to delay rendering the routed component until all necessary data have been fetched.
>   You need a resolver.